# How to select xaml object by x:Name

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, linq, xaml

I have a couple of ellipses which I need to select by its name, is there any way to do so?

My XAML:

```
<Grid Name="Fields"
      Height="300"
      Width="340">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse x:Name="f00" Margin="10" Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="f01" Margin="10" Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="f02" Margin="10" Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="f03" Margin="10" Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="f04" Margin="10" Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="f05" Margin="10" Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="f06" Margin="10" Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" />
</Grid>
```

If possible, I would prefer using linq

```
var a = from System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse ellipse in this.Fields
        where ellipse.Name == "f03"
        select ellipse;
```

Comment: What do you mean by select?

Comment: yes, but if this won't work, any other way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the FindName method and casting it as Ellipse should work:

```
var thisellipse = (Ellipse)this.FindName("f03");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution.

```
foreach (UIElement item in Fields.Children)
{
    Ellipse el = (Ellipse)item;
    if (el.Name == "f03")
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```